# Is there any existing Universal Importing method

Tags: import

Currently, when importing you have to decide OBJ, DAE, FBX or maybe another format. Is there any reason it can't just search a folder for all the file-types you & your addons support? Is there an existing way I can already do this? I think it would save me some time when guessing what model format someone has saved in.

Being able to double click model files (or drag & drop for importing) other than .blend would also be pretty handy but I don't think this was working last time I checked either.

Comment: Seems like an extremely straightforward upgrade it should have had a long time ago?

Comment: This is a pretty good question. Another step in blender's user-friendliness. You can also suggest improving this feature on development forums like https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/

Comment: I have done so, thanks for the suggestion!